# Christoffel symbols question about shortcut calculations

Tags: differential-geometry

I found these calculations on physics stackexchange https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/62907/ricci-tensor-for-a-3-sphere-without-math-packets?rq=1
$$
\Gamma^{i}_{ii} = \frac{1}{2}g^{ii}\partial_{i}g_{ii} = 0
$$

$$
\Gamma^{i}_{ji} = \frac{1}{2}g^{ii}\partial_{j}g_{ii}
$$

$$
\Gamma^{k}_{ll} = -\frac{1}{2}g^{kk}\partial_{k}g_{ll}
$$

$$
\Gamma^{k}_{lj} = \Gamma^{k}_{lk}\delta^{k}_{j} + \Gamma^{k}_{jk}\delta^{k}_{l} + \Gamma^{k}_{jj}\delta^{j}_{l} = 0
$$

The first three I know they are correct, but how can the last one be correct? Isn't it wrong to use an already used subscript to insert a summation? BTW, I would love it to be correct... :)

My question is: Can someone explain to me why is the last equation correct?

Comment: It is the first time that I see the same index, $k$ , appearing twice upstairs and once downstair in a formula $\Gamma _{lk}^k\delta_j^k$ what is the meaning of this ???

Comment: that's my question

Comment: not exactly, your question was "correct". I just think that it has no meaning.

Comment: are the chritoffel symbols, with all three indices distinct, equal to zero?

Comment: that's the translation of the last equation. it appears to be some kind of proof but..... how?!

Comment: of course not....